# Azure cognitive services, need help handling error when it doesn't detect face

Tags: javascript, ejs, azure-cognitive-services

[link to full repo](https://github.com/robregan/emotion-check)

So in my app it will analyze the face of an uploaded photo and return the results. But when it doesn't detect any faces the app crashes. i get "TypeError: Cannot read property 'faceAttributes' of undefined" in the console. for now I am just redirecting back to '/' but would rather show a message in the EJS. here is the post request:

```
app.post("/", upload.single("file-to-upload"), async (req, res) => {
  try {
    // Upload image to cloudinary
    const result = await cloudinary.uploader.upload(req.file.path);
    const imageUrl = result.secure_url;
    axios({
      method: "post",
      url: faceEndpoint,
      params: {
        returnFaceId: true,
        returnFaceAttributes:
          "age,gender,headPose,smile,facialHair,glasses," +
          "emotion,hair,makeup,occlusion,accessories,blur,exposure,noise",
      },
      data: {
        url: imageUrl,
      },
      headers: { "Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Key": subscriptionKey },
    })
      .then(function (response) {
        console.log("Status text: " + response.status);
        console.log("Status text: " + response.statusText);
        console.log(response.data[0]);
        res.render("result.ejs", {
          data: response.data[0].faceAttributes.emotion,
          img: imageUrl,
        });
      })
      .catch(function (error) {
        res.redirect('/')
        console.log(error);
      });
  } catch (err) {

    console.log(err);
  }
})
```

and in my EJS i just have a UL:

```
<ul>
  <li>Anger: <%= (data.anger * 100).toFixed(1) %>%</li>
  <li>Contempt: <%= (data.contempt * 100).toFixed(1) %>%</li>
  <li>Disgust: <%= (data.disgust * 100).toFixed(1) %>%</li>
  <li>Fear: <%= (data.fear * 100).toFixed(1) %>%</li>
  <li>Happiness: <%= (data.happiness *100).toFixed(1) %>%</li>
  <li>Neutral: <%= (data.neutral * 100).toFixed(1) %>%</li>
  <li>Sadness: <%= (data.sadness * 100).toFixed(1) %>%</li>
  <li>Surprise: <%= (data.surprise * 100).toFixed(1) %>%  </li>
</ul>
```

i've tried many variations of an if statement before the ul..

```
<% if(data.length == 0) { %>
 <h2> no faces detected </h2>
<% } else { %>
// ul goes here
<% } %>
```

also tried all these seperately..
`if(data[0].faceAttributes) if (data[0].faceAttributes.emotion) if(!data) if(typeof faceAttributes == 'undefined'`

I am pretty new to EJS and still trying to grasp some concepts so I am just not understanding some parts.

Comment: Do i need to add something to the res.render() in my app.js? am still new to this!

Comment: so i figured it out, gonna leave this up if anyone else stumbles across. what i did was send down null as an option if the response.data was [] or empty
 res.render("result.ejs", {
          data: response.data.length ? response.data[0].faceAttributes.emotion : null,
          img: imageUrl,
        });
and in my ejs just put if(!data) { <h2> no faces! </h2> else{ ... }